# How do I adjust figtext line spacing for when I have special characters in the text?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to add an subscript to some text for my figure caption. When I do this, the line with the subscript (line 2) moves up into the line above it (line 1). Is there easy any way around this issue? Using plt.text(...) seems like it could be tedious and time consuming.

If I don't use any special characters (i.e. $_{Sun}$) with figtext it works perfectly for me.

I also had something similar happen when I was doing the same thing with legend labels, so I'm guessing that any solution to this problem will solve that as well.

Below is the relevant code which I used:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pylab import *

plt.figure(1)

figtext(0.02,0.02,"Standard composition model, Spherical geometry\nT = 5000 K, log(g) = 3.0, Microturbulance = 2, Mass = 2M$_{Sun}$\nThe x-axis covers the range of the K-bandpass\n")

plt.show()
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Which version of matplotlib?

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.1 , with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have be a comment, if picture can be embedded in a comment. Anyway, this appears to be a bug in the interactive backend (in the following case, it is the `MacOSX` backend), when you save the plot into a .png or .pdf, etc, it will be rendered correctly.

Interactive:
[image]
Save it as .png or use `plt.savefig()`:
[image]